# C++ Array Error in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2012

I'm relearning C++ and I'm having some trouble with arrays in classes.  Here's a simplified version of what I'm working with

```
class Class
{
private:
    string array[2];
public:
    Class()
    {
        array[2] = {"Hello", "World"};
    }
    void printOut(int x)
    {
        cout << array[x];
    }
```

Visual Studio has an error on the first brace in the array initialization in the constructor (i.e. **{**"Hello", "World"}; which says "Error: expected an expression."  However, this problem does not occur when I initialize any other variable (not arrays).

I would have simple initialized the array values when I declared the array in the private section of the class as shown below.

```
class Class
{
private:
    string array[2] = {"Hello", "World"};
```

But Visual Studio gives an error on the equals sign saying "Error: data member initialization is now allowed."  This error does occur any time I try to initialize the variables at the same time they are declared in the private section of the class.

Any help or advice would be appreciated, thank in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays can only be initialized using that syntax, not assigned. You have to initialize it in the constructor's initialization list:

```
Class() : array{"Hello", "World"} {}
```

Alternatively, use `std::array` which can be assigned.

```
std::array<string, 2> array;

 Class()
 {
    array = {{ "Hello", "World" }};
 }
```

---

Another:

```
Class()
{
    array[0] = "Hello";
    array[1] = "World";
}
```

Comment: also, he is attempting to assign those two values to JUST the second element `[2]`. Array initialization requires there be no element specifier.

Comment: @Need4Sleep: He clearly wanted to assign the whole array, and was writing `array[2] = ` because he's used to local variables written as `string array[2] = {...};`  Pubby's fix is correct.

Comment: The parentheses can be removed from the *ctor-initializer-list*, can't they?  Just `Class() : array{"Hello", "World"} {}`

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, and actually the parenthesis were a compile error. Fixed now.

Comment: @Pubby I tried both, neither worked. With the first method, I tried both with and without the parenthesis as Ben Voigt mentioned. I get 3 errors: 1) on the first brace, "Error: expected a "(""; 2) on the end brace "Error: expected a ";"" (adding a ";" did nothing); and 3) on the first brace of the constructor, "Error: expected a declaration." With the second method (std::array) I put the declaration in the private section and initialized it in the constructor; I still get "Error: expected an expression" in the same place.

Comment: @Need4Sleep That was me being stupid, but I tried it without that and it created even more errors.

Comment: @gmaster You need a compliant C++11 compiler for it to work. Here's a working example code: http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1f5a599154ed959b1014ee17649341f7

Comment: @Pubby I'm using Visual Studio 2012; it's Visual C++ if I'm not mistaken...I have no idea what the difference is...

Comment: @gmaster Dunno, I'm not very familiar with Visual C++, maybe you need to add some compiler flag. Anyway, I added some code which should definitely work though, and you could also check out `boost::array` if `std::array` doesn't work.

Comment: Visual C++ 2012 does not support initializer lists and uniform initialization.

Comment: @Pubby What you put works, it just seems like a really inefficient way to initialize array values...Thanks for the help, I'll look into boost::array.